# How to assert content of generated file in unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I have a function that generates a csv file and returns the URL to download the file. Problem is i'm using `Uuid::uuid4()->toString()` due to a lot of files. How can I write a unit test using Codeception to verify that a given function works?

Essence of the test: I must pass an array to the function to create a csv, the function returns the path to the file with data, it is necessary to check that the function returns the correct path to the file.

Can I check that the file contains certain information, that is, the correctness of data export, if so, how can this be done?

Class to test:

```php
class CsvExport
{
    const UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "uploads/csv/";

    public function create(array $data): string
    {
        $id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();

        if (empty($data)) {
            throw new \DomainException('Array is empty');
        }

        $file = $this->buildFileByPath($id);
        $write = fopen($file, 'w+');

        foreach ($data as $items) {
            fputcsv($write, $items);
        }
        fclose($write);

        return $file;
    }

    private function buildFileByPath(string $id): string
    {
        return self::UPLOAD_DIRECTORY . $id . '.csv';
    }
}
```

And my unsuccessful attempt to write a test:

```php
class CsvExportTest extends Unit
{
    /**
     * @var UnitTester
     */
    protected UnitTester $tester;

    
    public function testCsvExport():void
    {
        $data = $data = [['Name', 'age', 'Gender']];
        $service = new CsvExport();
        $path = $service->create($data);
        Assert::assertEquals($path, $service->create($data));
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to test? That the CSV file contains certain content? Maybe Flysystem helps you to abstract the filesystem

Comment: I supplemented the question at your request

Comment: Also think about it, is it really the returned path you want to test? What does this tell you? On it's own it does not tell you if the file was created with the correct content which seems to be the main goal of the function. The path is actually handeled by `$this->buildFileByPath($id);` which you could test on it's own.

Comment: how can i check the contents of the file?

Comment: Why not open the file and read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Codeception, you can use [seeFileFound](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Filesystem#seeFileFound) and [seeFileContentsEqual](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Filesystem#seeFileContentsEqual) methods of Filesystem module.

```php
<?php
    class CsvExportTest extends Unit
    {
        /**
         * @var UnitTester
         */
        protected UnitTester $tester;
    
        
        public function testCsvExport():void
        {
            $data = [['Name', 'age', 'Gender']];
            $service = new CsvExport();
            $path = $service->create($data);
            $this->tester->seeFileFound($path);
            $this->tester->seeFileContentEquals("Name,age,Gender\n");
        }
    }
```

Filesystem module must be installed using `composer require --dev codeception/module-filesystem`
and enabled in suite configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can assert content of your file using [assertStringMatchesFormatFile()](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/assertions.html#assertstringmatchesformatfile) method from PHPUnit.

So your test will be look like this:

```
public function testCsvExport(): void
{
    $data = [['Name', 'age', 'Gender']];

    $service = new CsvExport();
    $path = $service->create($data);

    Assert::assertStringMatchesFormatFile($path, 'Name,age,Gender');
}
```

In this way this unit tests will be more useful, because you ensure that file was really created and it contains data in valid format.